# Pending message - all 3 buttons (accept, reject, edit) missing from Yahoo Group

Tags: javascript

(Chrome) Console says:

```
RAPID WARNING: Specified module not in DOM: masterNav combo...
RAPID WARNING: Specified module not in DOM: uhWrapper combo...
DARLA notice: 310 combo...
The page at 'https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/.../management/pendingmessages' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://...: this content should also...
```

Since all 3 buttons (accept, reject, edit) have vanished, what is easiest way to access Pending Messages (to delete the problem messages)?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Pending messages - all three function buttons (accept, reject, edit) missing/do not display at all - so how can one fix the problem when all three buttons have completely vanished from pending messages webpage? There are no buttons to click on. There is one visible pending message stuck with no buttons to press at all and other pending messages there yet hidden from view. Pending messages are frozen in place so to speak with no access. Thank you.